# Matrices, zero in diagonal

Tags: matrices

I have an infinite matrix $J:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a_1 & 0 &0 \\ a_1 &0 & a_2 &0 \\ 0&a_2&0&\ddots \\0&0&\ddots&0 \end{pmatrix} $

I need to show that $-J=D.J.D$ where D:=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0& 0 &0 \\ 0 &-1 & 0 &0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\0&0&0&\ddots \end{pmatrix}

Comment: What is matrix multiplication when they are infinite?

Comment: normally I truncate the matrix into $n*n$ and hence once proved it applies for the infinite matrix

Comment: I don't know what a infinite matrix is, but multiplying naively, it follows easily. The left multiplication multiplies the even rows by $-1$, the right multiplication multiplies the even columns by $-1$ and due to the way $J$ looks like, the result follows.